# Yii2 how add a new action button in grid

Tags: php, yii2

I have following grid.

```
    $gridColumns = [
                'class'=>'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
                'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
                'template' => '{delete}{my_button}', 
            ],

    echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'filterModel' => $filterModel,
            ],
        ]);
```

I want add to `template` a new action button for example `{my_button}`.

Comment: this is not duplicate question.

Answer (score 8):

You should simply add a `buttons` param to your column, e.g. :

```
'template' => '{my_button}', 
'buttons' => [
    'my_button' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
        return Html::a('My Action', ['my-action', 'id'=>$model->id]);
    },
]
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$buttons-detail

Comment: I tried this but it does not render new custom buttons. What can be the problem?